# Exporting Service now Graphical Flow

Tags: javascript, servicenow

My goal is to export flow created using the graphical editor in service now, with the intention to use as an easy way to demonstrate flows to team members.

The way i want this to be able to go to the flow's page, open its options and "copy snipped", or have an option to export as a format for visio or other xml/json formats.

However currently with the options i can find, i am unable to find any general export function, instead some sub flows have an option to "copy snippet"

I have tried some "better than nothing" options like, some of the "non pre-configured" sub flows are able to be opened for editing in a flyout window and there they can be coppied as a snipped, like: [image]

where as when trying to open non-preconfigured sub flows this is what shows[image]

there is an option to copy the whole flow, however this is only internal within the instance and doesnt allow to be coppied as script text